# After placing a view inside a View Controller, the attributes inspector for that view is completely blank. Why is this happening?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title said, I created a single view application in xcode, selected the view (not the view controller the view) and when I went to the attributes inspector to change the color of the view, there is nothing there? I have no idea why I am not able to edit the attributes of my view in the attributes inspector.

EDIT: Image of problem
[image: The view is selected, the attributes inspector is empty]

Comment: It will be easier to understand your problem if you could put a screenshot of what you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to click on `View` to actually show the `Attributes inspector`. You probably accidentally clicked on it once which hides it.
Check the screenshot below. As you can see it displays `Show` when you hover over `View`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Word "View" and you will see all the attributes as currently the "View" tab is closed.

Answer (score -1):

when you select the view and click on the attributes inspector see that background color property change the color you want.And also the attributes inspector  click on the view show at the left side may be this hide so you can't see anything in the inspector area.